# Input XML data doen't match with the output XML format

Tags: xml, perl

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--00/00/0000 12:35:25 AM-->
<Physical xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <Pro managementID="22000020">
    <Identification Type="XXXXX" >          
      <Address>
        <Data>test</Data>        
      </Address>
      <Phone>
        <Number>0000</Number>
      </Phone>
      <Email>test@com</Email>
    </Identification>       
  </Pro>
</Physical>
```

Script:

I am trying to change the value of the tag and print the rest to a new output xml file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;     

  my $xml = XML::Simple->new(ForceContent => 1,);
  my $xmlData = $xml->XMLin('input.xml') or die$!;     

  print Dumper (\$xmlData);

  foreach my $xmlKey ( keys %{$xmlData} ){
   if ( $xmlKey =~ m/Pro/){
       print ${$xmlData}{$xmlKey}{Identification}{Address}{Data}="hello";
    }
  }

XMLout(
    $xmlData,
    KeepRoot => 1,
    NoAttr => 0,
    OutputFile => $xml_out,
);
```

**Outout XML:**

```
<opt xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Pro managementID="22000020">
     <Identification Type="XXXXX">
      <Address Data="hello" />
      <Email>test@com</Email>
      <Phone name="Number">0000</Phone>
    </Identification>
  </Pro>
</opt>
```

I am able to change the value, but whem i am trying to write the data to the ouput the format has been changed.Can any one guide me to get the same input data with changed value as output.

Comment: And that's why you don't use XML::Simple for output.

Answer (score 4):

use XML::LibXML this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $input;
while(<>) {
    $input .= $_;
}
my $xml_doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $input);
my $xpath_ctx = new XML::LibXML::XPathContext($xml_doc);
$xpath_ctx->find("/Physical/Pro/Identification/Address/Data")->get_node(0)->firstChild()->setData("hello");
my $xml_data = $xpath_ctx->find("/")->get_node(0)->toString(1);

print $xml_data;
```

XML::LibXML is much faster and with the help of the XPath, the manipulation of the `$xml_doc` is much easier.

more infos you can find [here](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0008/LibXML.pod)

Comment: Why do you not use `load_xml( location => 'input.xml' )` ?

Comment: @choroba there is no any reason ... you can use it as you like

Comment: @choroba nahh ... both ways are simple enough ... depends on what you are trying to do

Comment: @memosdp: It really is wrong to read the entire file into memory unless you need to do so for other purposes. It clearly *isn't* as simple this way as just providing the file path to the call to `load_xml`.

Comment: @Borodin i agree ... with big documents should be a problem and moreover i don't trust so much the memory handling of perl ... but the actual question don't have to do with this ... i just copied the xml provided by the OP and i gave a fast example ... that's all. I mean i didn't write the code to handle with efficiency the source of the xml document but just to illustrate the usage of the LibXML. How to handle the source of the xml document, depends on what you are trying to do with the whole interface you are going to implement.

Comment: The OP wrote `XMLin('input.xml')`. The obvious parallel is to offer `load_xml(location => 'input.xml')` as choroba said. I am fairly certain that you simply weren't aware of this option in `LibXML` and I wish you had just backed down and modified your code instead of attempting to preserve your stance, which is now in shambles

Comment: @Borodin sorry but i can't understand your stance now ... this is an offensive comment? 'in shambles' ?!?!?!?!?! nothing is in shambles ...  and i don't trying to preserve my stance ... what is this you are saying? i know everything about LibXML if you wanna know ... not only in PERL but in C also

Comment: @memosdp: I am simply saying that you have complicated your answer by adding the code to read the file into memory. It is unnecessary to do that because it neither mirrors the OP's code nor fulfils any requirement. Therefore it seems that you made a simple mistake that you are refusing to correct, rather than having a valid reason for your choice. This dialogue has gone on far too long and I will not answer any more of your comments

Comment: @Borodin okay then ... i prefer to don't change to `load_xml(location => 'input.xml')` because the point of the question is not this

Answer (score 2):

Use a different XML handling module. For example, this script uses [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::XSH2;

xsh << 'END';
    open input.xml ;
    for //*[xsh:matches(name(),'Pro')]/Identification/Address/Data
        set . 'hello' ;
    save :b ;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

An XML::Twig version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'Pro/Identification/Address/Data' => sub { $_->set_text( 'hello'); $_->flush; } },
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
              )
         ->parsefile( 'input.xml');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way w/XML::Rules

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Rules;

my @rules = (
  Data => sub { $_[1]{_content} =~ s/test/hello/; return $_[0] => $_[1] },
);
my $xr = XML::Rules->new(
  rules => \@rules,
  style => 'filter',
);

$xr->filterfile('input.xml');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got `NoAttr` set to zero for the output.

Isn't that the opposite of what you want?

> NoAttr => 1
>
> When used with XMLout(), the generated XML will contain no attributes.
>   All hash key/values will be represented as nested elements instead.

NoAttr would stop

```
<Phone>
    <Number>0000</Number>
```

turning into

```
 <Phone name="Number">
```